# Convert a decomposed time series matrix to a list of vectors in R?

Tags: list, matrix, time-series, decomposition

I am new to R and trying to find a shortcut to deal with the following matrices that result from my time series decomposition of seasonal data. I would like to print each matrix as a time-consecutive single column.

```
$x
       Qtr1   Qtr2   Qtr3   Qtr4
2011        -26.93 -26.88 -27.35
2012 -27.18 -26.64 -27.26 -27.46
2013 -25.88 -27.02 -26.84 -28.05
2014 -26.61 -26.86 -26.64 -26.51
2015 -26.72 -26.98 -26.39 -26.87

$seasonal
           Qtr1       Qtr2       Qtr3       Qtr4
2011             0.0362500  0.0068750 -0.3871875
2012  0.3440625  0.0362500  0.0068750 -0.3871875
2013  0.3440625  0.0362500  0.0068750 -0.3871875
2014  0.3440625  0.0362500  0.0068750 -0.3871875
2015  0.3440625  0.0362500  0.0068750 -0.3871875

$trend
          Qtr1      Qtr2      Qtr3      Qtr4
2011                  NA        NA -27.04875
2012 -27.06000 -27.12125 -26.97250 -26.85750
2013 -26.85250 -26.87375 -27.03875 -27.11000
2014 -27.06500 -26.84750 -26.66875 -26.69750
2015 -26.68125 -26.69500        NA        NA

$random
           Qtr1       Qtr2       Qtr3       Qtr4
2011                    NA         NA  0.0859375
2012 -0.4640625  0.4450000 -0.2943750 -0.2153125
2013  0.6284375 -0.1825000  0.1918750 -0.5528125
2014  0.1109375 -0.0487500  0.0218750  0.5746875
2015 -0.3828125 -0.3212500         NA         NA
```

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution

`x_dataframe <- data.frame(z$x, z$seasonal, z$trend, z$random)`